# why onCleared in my viewModel is called when I close the fragment using navigation component?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I have tried to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50983738/when-is-the-viewmodel-oncleared-called), but I think I cant find the solution.

say I have FragmentA and Fragment B. I move to fragment B using this code

```
val nextDestination = AFragmentDirections.actionToB()
findNavController().navigate(nextDestination)
```

when I back from fragment B to fragment A, `onDestroy` in my fragment is called and then `onCleared` on my ViewModel is also get called.

but when I rotate the phone (configuration changes),  when `onDestroy` is called, then `onCleared` is NOT called.

so I previously assume, when `onDestroy` called, then `onCleared` is also called. but it is not. why there is different behaviour like this ? when configuration changes is different from fragment navigation ?

I am confused when exactly the `onCleared` is called

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole point of a ViewModel is to survive configuration changes as per the [ViewModel documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel), so it is expected that ViewModels are not cleared over a configuration change.

However, each ViewModel is associated with a [`ViewModelStoreOwner`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelStoreOwner). This could be your activity or it could be a Fragment. It is up to that `ViewModelStoreOwner` to understand when it is being destroyed due to a temporary change (such as a configuration change) or a permanent destruction. It is only in that permanent destruction that `onCleared()` for each ViewModel is called.

For an activity, that permanent destruction happens when the activity is finished (i.e., `finish()` is called or the behavior of `onBackPressed()` leads to `finish()` being called).

For a Fragment, that permanent destruction happens **when the Fragment is popped off the back stack.** This is what happens when you pop fragment B off the back stack and return to Fragment A - Fragment B is removed from the FragmentManager, it goes through `onDestroy()`, and its ViewModels are cleared.

Fragment A will have the same thing happen to it once *it* is popped off the back stack or, if it is the only thing on the back stack, when the activity is finished when you hit the system back button.