# Why ViewModel onCleared() is called when user navigates to another fragment but it doesn't called after device rotation?

Tags: android, android-viewmodel

I have read different post where it is mentioned that `onCleared()` of `ViewModel` is called in between `onDestroyView` and `onDetach`. So when I leave Fragment and navigate to another Fragment
`onDestroyView` is called ,then `onCleared()` followed by `onDestroy()`.
when I do screen rotation `onDestroyView` is called and then `onDestroy()` .
During rotation `onCleared()` isn't called. Wondering how it understands when onCleared() method should be called.
I was expecting after I leave fragment and return to Fragment the viewModel still should be alive.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50983738/when-is-the-viewmodel-oncleared-called

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When is the viewmodel onCleared called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50983738/when-is-the-viewmodel-oncleared-called)